# How to check if a Site collection exists using App model (JSOM,CSOM)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom

Is there a way to check if a site collection exists before creating the site collection?

I am doing it using the App/Add-in model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PnP-Sites-Core extension method: `CheckIfSiteExists(this Tenant tenant, string siteFullUrl, string status)`

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Extensions/TenantExtensions.cs#L144

```
public static bool CheckIfSiteExists(this Tenant tenant, string siteFullUrl, string status)
{
    bool ret = false;
    //Get the site name
    var url = new Uri(siteFullUrl);
    var siteDomainUrl = url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    int siteNameIndex = url.AbsolutePath.IndexOf('/', 1) + 1;
    var managedPath = url.AbsolutePath.Substring(0, siteNameIndex);
    var siteRelativePath = url.AbsolutePath.Substring(siteNameIndex);
    var isSiteCollection = siteRelativePath.IndexOf('/') == -1;

    //Judge whether this site collection is existing or not
    if (isSiteCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            var properties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteFullUrl, false);
            tenant.Context.Load(properties);
            tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
            ret = properties.Status.Equals(status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        catch (ServerException ex)
        {
            if (IsUnableToAccessSiteException(ex))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Let's retry to see if this site collection was recycled
                    var deletedProperties = tenant.GetDeletedSitePropertiesByUrl(siteFullUrl);
                    tenant.Context.Load(deletedProperties);
                    tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
                    ret = deletedProperties.Status.Equals(status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // eat exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Judge whether this sub web site is existing or not
    else
    {
        var subsiteUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "{0}{1}{2}", siteDomainUrl, managedPath, siteRelativePath.Split('/')[0]);
        var subsiteRelativeUrl = siteRelativePath.Substring(siteRelativePath.IndexOf('/') + 1);
        var site = tenant.GetSiteByUrl(subsiteUrl);
        var subweb = site.OpenWeb(subsiteRelativeUrl);
        tenant.Context.Load(subweb, w => w.Title);
        tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
        ret = true;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of site collection in Office 365 using CSOM

```
var token = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken("00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", 
     tenantAdminUri.Authority, null).AccessToken;
 using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken("https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com", token))
 {
     var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
     SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
     clientContext.Load(spp);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach(SiteProperties sp in spp)
    {
        // you'll get your site collections here
    }
}
```

Reference Blog are here [Link](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2014-4-Get_list_of_site_collections_using_CSOM_in_Office365.aspx)

If you want to use Rest API then

```
function searchSites(webUrl,success, failure) {
var url = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        success(data.d.query);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failure(data);
    }
});
}
```

//print sites info

```
searchSites(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
function(query){
    var resultsCount = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
    for(var i = 0; i < resultsCount;i++) {
      var row =  query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i];
        var siteUrl = row.Cells.results[6].Value;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(siteUrl));
   }   
},
function(error){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: The second method using JS and the search API won't return all sites. It will just return the sites you have permissions on.

Comment: Just a detail but this will retrieve the first 300 site collections only http://sprecipe.com/2015/11/04/sharepoint-online-retrieve-all-site-collections-via-csom/